# Can I use MySql for free on my machine for developing my application?

Tags: mysql, licensing

I have one query related to mysql licensing. I am developing a desktop application for commercial purpose and using mysql community server (5.0) as backend database server.
We dont install mysql server and driver from our application installer. If user wants to install our application on his machine then he first needs to install MySql server and driver by themselve and then he can install our application. This is because of GPL license terms.

Now my question is can I use MySql for free on my machine for developing my application or do I need any commercial license for application development?

As MySql is a freeware, I am using it on my machine for development of my application. Am I doing something wrong?
I am confuse about how this GPL license works? I am not able to understand its terms and conditions. I know only one thing is that I cannt ship mysql installer with our product, but about development purpose I have no idea how license works.

Comment: Gr8 guys... Thanks for your valuable Ideas...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 12):

The usage of MySQL for development is free. As you are not giving away that product (MySQL), no GPL restrictions apply.

If you want to distribute MySQL in some form, the licenses apply. See: [MySQL commercial license](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem)

> OEMs (Original Equipment Manufacturers), ISVs (Independent Software Vendors), VARs (Value Added Resellers) and other distributors that combine and distribute commercially licensed software with MySQL software and do not wish to distribute the source code for the commercially licensed software under version 2 of the GNU General Public License (the "GPL") must enter into a commercial license agreement with Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

Simple explanation of MySQL License (without driver hassle/crude explanation):

Case 1:

If you are an individual trying to solve your problems then no need to pay license fee.

Case 2:

If you are an individual trying to market your application that requires MySQL then 
a) If you plan to release your application free - No license Fee 
b) If you plant not to release your app free    - License need to be bought at less price

Case 3:

If you are a company that uses MySQL 
a) internal apps with lot of users using MYSQL server - License required 
   (because this is believed to make money in terms of savings)
b) external apps - License required

Cheers,
SpiderMan

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's always been available under the GPL so you can use it for free anywhere. You can pay for support and you can also pay for the other non-community editions. It does look like the Cluster version is also free. As far as reselling it I'm not sure. You probably have to get the user to download it to their machine when they install it, but I'm not sure. You may be able to distribute it along with your application.

Comment: As I have understood it, it's free to use "as is" but you are not allowed to embed it into your application and distribute it, atleast not charge for the software in that case.

Comment: GPL doesn't prohibit charging. It just requires source availability of original code / modified code / derivative works under the same license.

Answer (score 2):

Using a GPL server doesn't mean you have to put your own application under GPL (any more than every app developed on Linux must be GPLed).

Also, you would certainly be able to distribute mysql along with your application - at minimum, as a separate installer on the CD, or download web page. You just have to make the source (of mysql) available also.

But I suspect there is probably no issue putting it in your own installer too, one to check with a lawyer though.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps off-topic but you might want to consider [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for the backend database if it's a single-user desktop application. It doesn't involve running a service and it's free for both development and run-time. Plus you can distribute it with your application.

Comment: it _is_ offtopic, but SQLite is far better for most desktp-bound applications.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Is free to download and use.  They also have an enterprise version available for subscription purchase and provides you with the database server as well as very nice premium support package and very robust utilities and tools such as Query Analyzer.  As well as using it locally on any computer you want to install it on you can also sign up for free shared database servers.  I would recommend signing up at:
http://www.mysqlforfree.com/ 
They are a new website I found and are taking off, so far I've seen more features with them than any of the other free mysql websites.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, it's fine to use it as a development tool because you are not then reselling it or making money from it.

Where I used to work all our internal and external web sites were using MySql without the need for a licence.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I like about Postgresql over MySQL is that it has a slightly more open licensing policy:

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#Licensing